# Starlette catch all routes and http methods

Tags: python, starlette

I want to make my function `proxy` accepts ALL paths and all HTTP methods, everything that hits the Starlette app I want to proxy function handles it.

```
async def proxy(request: Request):
    pass


routes = [
    Route("/", endpoint=proxy),
]

app = Starlette(routes=routes)
```

I tried the code above, but no luck.

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using an optional, catch-all path.

```py
routes = [
    Route("/{path:path}", endpoint=proxy),
]
```

It can be empty OR anything else.